# Vulnerability Title : SSH Weak Mac Algorithm Enabled for version Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS server

Tags: ssh, mac

Hi team we have a vulnerability reported for SSH Weak Mac Algorithm Enabled for one Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS VERSION server, we tried to mitigate with available MAC keys from different website suggested but didn't work, kindly suggest with a strong MAC key algorithm to enable as we need to mitigate it, kindly assist.

Comment: Your question should include the CVE number of the specific vulnerability that you are asking about. "*a vulnerability reported*" is too vague to be answerable.

Comment: Sorry its my bad below is the version details of the Ubuntu based  server

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

Vulnerability title: SSH Weak Mac Algorithm Enabled

Recommendations from report:

Recommended to disable the weak algorithms and enable the strong and supported algorithms.

CVE number : N/A i do not have since its internal.